# Use one monitor as multiple monitors

Tags: software-recommendation, multiple-monitors, display

It is nice to use multiple monitors for developers. You can maximise each window in a specific monitor, windows can stick to corners of specific monitors.

There are ultrawide monitors in the market (e.g. LG 34UM95). Is there any software that can divide a single monitor into 2 or 3 parts horizontally, and each part would act like a separate monitor?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I took this from [an answer at superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/115076/how-to-vertically-split-widescreen-into-two-virtual-workspaces-on-ubuntu-gnome) please give them an upvote if it helps you,

you can use [fakexinerama](https://www.xpra.org/trac/wiki/FakeXinerama) for achieving what you want:

> Fake Xinerama is a replacement libXinerama library that instead   of
>   querying the XServer reads ~/.fakexinerama and provides fake
>   information about Xinerama screens based on this file. It can be
>   used to fake a Xinerama setup even on computers with just one monitor 
>   or to fake Xinerama setup other than one specified in the XServer
>   configuration (e.g. making one screen smaller when using two same
>   screens). It's probably only useful for developers.

See that question for more detail.

Answer (score 10):

You can also take a look at the [FakeXRandR](https://github.com/phillipberndt/fakexrandr) project.

> FakeXRandR is a tool to cheat an X11 server to believe that there are more monitors than there actually are. It hooks into libXRandR and libXinerama and replaces certain, configurable monitor configurations with multiple virtual monitors. A tool that comes with this package can be used to configure how monitors are split.

There is also a nice graphical editor to quickly split your display in as many region / dipsosition you want :

[image: screeshot]

Answer (score 2):

This can be done in XRandR 1.5 without additional software albeit it's undocumented at the moment (at least I could not find a documentation for this). While neither fakexinerama nor FakeXRandR have worked for me on Xubuntu, this solution has finally split the screen into two.

To split the monitor do the following:

1. Enter `xrandr` into the terminal to check the output name and current resolution of the display you want to split.
   On my system the result was:

   ```
   Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 32767 x 32767
   HDMI1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
   HDMI2 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 509mm x 286mm
      1920x1080     60.00*+  50.00    59.94
      1920x1080i    60.00    50.00    59.94  
      1600x900      60.00  
      1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
      1152x864      75.00  
      1280x720      60.00    50.00    59.94  
      1024x768      75.08    60.00  
      800x600       75.00    60.32  
      720x576       50.00  
      720x576i      50.00
      720x480       60.00    59.94
      720x480i      60.00    59.94
      640x480       75.00    60.00    59.94
      720x400       70.08
   VGA1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
   VIRTUAL1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
   ```

   We can see that my monitor is connected to HDMI2 and the resolution is set to 1920x1080.
2. Add 2 virtual monitors with the `xrandr --setmonitor` command ensuring that they overlap with your physical display and are placed next to each other. The syntax of the command is (without quotes):

   ```
   xrandr --setmonitor "monitor_name" "width_px"/"width_mm"x"height_px"/"height_mm"+"x_offset_px"+"y_offset_px" "output_name"
   ```

   For my system it was:

   ```
   xrandr --setmonitor HDMI2~1 960/254x1080/286+0+0 HDMI2
   xrandr --setmonitor HDMI2~2 960/255x1080/286+960+0 none
   ```
3. While the above has already configured the virtual monitors on my system the changes haven't been applied until I have executed (it seems to refresh xrandr):

   ```
   xrandr --fb 1921x1080
   xrandr --fb 1920x1080
   ```

To persist the changes after reboot you would want to execute these commands when you login. You can do so by appending the commands at the end of your `~/.profile` file.

Comment: Works on xfce 4.12, doesn't on kde5 (plasma, kwin 5.10.5).

Comment: seem like this should work, but I cannot get it to function on a recent ubuntu. Would welcome knowing if anyone else has got it working

Comment: I tested in ubuntu 21.10, does not work, too

Answer (score 0):

I believe that this question was asked first here [superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/115076/how-to-vertically-split-widescreen-into-two-virtual-workspaces-on-ubuntu-gnome). But more likely than not, everyone provided complicated answers with no one clear solution or workable solution.

After going through that avoiding the CLI responses, I picked the following:
[xmonad](https://xmonad.org/)

Then I was lucky to also happen across [this list](https://www.tecmint.com/best-tiling-window-managers-for-linux/) of solutions. All the best.